# How to make a JLayeredPane transparent with visible figures?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel, jlayeredpane

**My JLayeredPane's overlap the way I want them to, but I can't seem to create a transparent background for the top layer.

I'm trying to create a game, called Kamisado, where the board 8x8 has different color grids and figures on top of it.

I created a board and figures in separated classes as `JLabels`, then added each of them to separate `JLayeredPanes`, which were later added to the main `JFrame` "board".

Although you can see layers, the front layer with figures isn't transparent to see the layer with the board behind it.

How can I make a front layer to be transparent to the board behind it?

[image]

In separate classes, I create a `JLabel`, set `Bounds`, `Icon`, `Visibility(true)`, and `Opaque(true)`. For the tile class, I set the background color as well.

```
 public class Board extends JFrame implements MouseListener {

    static Container cont;
    static Board board;
    static Tile[][] tile;
    static Monster[][] monster;
    static int height = 800;
    static int width = 900;
    int i = 8;
    int j = 8;

    static JLayeredPane pTile = new JLayeredPane();
    static JLayeredPane pMon = new JLayeredPane();

    Board() {
        super("Kamisado");
//      pane = this.getLayeredPane();
        this.setSize(new Dimension(height, width));
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        
        pMon.setLayout(new GridLayout(8, 8));
        pTile.setLayout(new GridLayout(8, 8));

        tile = new Tile[8][8];
        monster = new Monster[8][8];
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                tilePane(i,j);
                monsterPane(i,j);
            }
        }
        this.add(pTile);
        this.add(pMon);
    //  this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Board.board = this;
    }
    static void monsterPane(int i, int j) {
        Monster m = addMonster(i, j);
        pMon.add(m);
        pMon.setVisible(true);
        pMon.setOpaque(true);
        pMon.repaint();
    }

    static public Monster addMonster(int i, int j) {
        monster[i][j] = new Monster(i, j, board);
        
        return monster[i][j];

    }
    static void tilePane(int i, int j) {
        Tile m = addTile(i, j);
        pTile.add(m);
        pTile.setVisible(true);
        pTile.repaint();
    }

    static public Tile addTile(int i, int j) {
        tile[i][j] = new Tile(i, j, board);
        
        return tile[i][j];
    }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: A `JLayeredPane` is not a layer but the component containing layers. To add layers, use `getLayeredPane()` to get the `JFrame`’s existing `JLayeredPane` and add your objects to it. Don’t add more `JLayeredPane`s.

Comment: If you want transparency then you should be using `setOapaque(false)` on the top level component.

Comment: [How to Use Layered Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html)